# Erroe when trying to execute Hive Command

Tags: hadoop, hive

cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive
17/02/15 16:27:42 WARN mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present. Continuing without it.

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.8.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

When I am trying to launch Hive above problrms happening.
Also when I tried to know hive version i am using it shows the same error.Please help me with this

Comment: Its a common error, follow the link: http://doctuts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hive.html

Comment: I have followed the link you have given do all the needfull,but still the error is same,One thing i have noticed hive is initialized using configuration file in /etc/hive/conf but in the link u but it should load from /usr/lib/hive/ directory..

Comment: Did you started the metastore service?

Comment: I have posted a command to start the metastore, start the metastore and let me know if you steel facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that error is coming due to Meta Store is not started, try to start the Meta Store and if you getting any error while starting, then follow my answer on below Link.

[SemanticException in Hive Shell Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231212/semanticexception-in-hive-shell-mode/50231696#50231696)