# Error while working on hive which is installed on edgenode

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop/HIve learning and struggling to fix this, for a distributed hadoop environment where should hive and pig need to install, is this edge node or where my hadoop installed

Hadoop installed on different server say hadoopVM, 2 separate data nodes DN1, DN2 & Edge Nodes from where I can submit jobs to hadoop to load any files to HDFS

till here i have no issue, i am trying to install hive edge node and getting below error

[Attached error which i am getting on edgenode server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPQ7.png)

Comment: Did you started your meta store service, error seems that Meta store service is not started.

Comment: Yes i have done that already but it was not working, there was some issue with SSL and hive-site.xml configuration after correction it resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Meta Store service is not started. start the service by issuing the following command in one of the session and don't close that session, and parallel start another session and try to use hive.

Active session mode:

```
sudo hive --service metastore
```

Background service mode:
If you add "&&" then service will be started and keep running as a background process.

```
sudo hive --service metastore &&
```

Altarnative:

If you still facing the problem then this is the problem because the new version of MySQL, you can refer my answer at below link.

[SemanticException in Hive Shell Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231212/semanticexception-in-hive-shell-mode/50231696#50231696)